# What does "No Order on Count" mean as an disposition of a charge?

Tags: trial, process, illinois

I'm looking at some case histories from the Cook County, IL criminal courts, and some charges have a disposition of "No Order on Count." What might that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this glossary of abbreviations, NOOC stands for "No order on court," which is explained as "charge dropped -- Illinois":

https://smwreports.sterlingdirect.com/documents/CourtAbbreviations.pdf

Note "court" with an "r," not "count" with an "n."

It is remarkable how few Google hits there were for the exact phrase "no order on court."  There were two instances of this document, a news article about tennis and a book result on badminton.

However, "no order on count" had even fewer hits, namely, two different links to this stackexchange question.

Comment: Hmm.. in this data there are 9000 entries of "No Order On Count" no "No Order on Court"

Comment: @fgregg in what data?

Comment: It's an extract of case event histories for about 15 years of felony cases from the Court's record keeping system.

Comment: @fgregg do you have a link to that data?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.